# How does one automatically update Route53 from a raspberry pi server at home?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, aws, dynamic-dns

A raspberry pi at home running Rasbian Jessie 8.0 is running Apache.  Using `dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com` produces an IPv4 that is used to update the value in the record sets of the hosted zone in AWS's route 53 circled in red in the following image.
[image: Route 53 Record Sets]
Testing the domain name is successful.

What I'd like to do now is update AWS Route53 whenever my home's dynamic IP address changes from within the raspberry pi with out any assistance from me.

Please let me know if you require anymore information.

Comment: I don't use AWS Route 53... but does this help [Github: aws-dyndns](https://github.com/famzah/aws-dyndns)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to stick with AWS tools follow these steps:

1. Create an AWS IAM User, e.g. **dns-updater** and assign it this AWS managed policy: **AmazonRoute53FullAccess**. Generate *secret* and *access* keys for the user.
2. Install *AWS-CLI* (e.g. `pip install awscli`)
3. Configure *AWS-CLI*, enter the above secret and access keys: `aws configure`

From a cron job on the RPi run a script that does the following:

1. Obtain the external public IP, e.g. `RPI_EXT_IP=$(curl http://ifconfig.co)`
2. Create an update JSON file:

   ```
   cat > /tmp/r53-update.json << __EOF__
     {
       "Changes": [
         {
           "Action": "UPSERT",
           "ResourceRecordSet": {
             "Name": "rpi.your-route53-domain.com",
             "Type": "A",
             "TTL": 600,
             "ResourceRecords": [
               {
                 "Value": "${RPI_EXT_IP}"
               }
             ]
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   __EOF__
   ```
3. Call *AWS-CLI* to update the Route53 record using the above JSON file, replace the *hosted zone id* with a real id of your Route53 zone:

   ```
   ~ $ aws route53 change-resource-record-sets \
           --hosted-zone-id ZXCVBNMEXAMPLE \
           --change-batch file:///tmp/r53-update.json
   ```

Let us know if you need any clarification.

Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped :)